# Masonry grid gets taller after I insert a new grid item

Tags: javascript, css, masonry

I'm trying to create a very basic grid layout with Masonry.js here. Basically I want to dynamically add a new grid item to my grid. This works normally except for one weird issue I see no matter how I try and implement this. When I add the new element, the item that was first in the list and all the way to the left moves to the far right side of the grid, and a space appears between the first and second items.

Before appending anything my grid looks like this

[image]

With this structure for html

```
        <div id="session-holder">
                <div class="grid">
                    <div id="add-session" class="grid-item"><img src="Icons/add-orange.png"></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"></div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
var element = document.querySelector(".grid")
var layout = new Masonry(element, {
    itemSelector : ".grid-item",
    fitWidth: true,
})
```

CSS

```
#session-holder{
    height: fit-content;
}
.grid{
    width: 540px;
}
#add-session{
    border-width: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ff7c4d;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
#add-session:hover{
    opacity: .7;
}
#add-session:hover > img{
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
#add-session > img{
    transition: transform .2s linear;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#next-session{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: orangered;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid-item{
    background-color: #333333;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 130px;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

After adding the item the grid looks like this...

[image]

As expected the new grid item fills in the last spot, but now I also have this giant gap at the top to deal with. The space that's inserted at the top appears to be the same height as one row of grid-items (probably not a coincidence).

I could just use css grids to achieve the same appearance, but I like that Masonry grid-items are animated (which is something I really don't want to try and reproduce).

I've looked around in Masonry's documentation for a solution or possible explanation but haven't found a smoking pistol.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] as I cannot reproduce this with your current code, working exanple: http://jsfiddle.net/bqmnkewo/

Comment: Thats interesting. I see you're example is working normally. Before I do anything else let me compare your example with my code to see if I can get it working normally.

Comment: using the code you have there does work. I'm not sure why but something I'm doing in mine is creating that extra space. I'll take a closer look at my code and see if I can't figure it out. Thanks!